# iOS: Change Device Volume

Tags: iphone, ios, volume

Is there a way to change the volume of the device? I've seen several apps do it.

I have a desktop version of the iOS app and the device will be able to be controlled to some extent over the network. One of the things I want to allow the user to do is change the device volume and then play a sound. This can help if you loose your iPhone in a crack in your couch again, but can't find it.

Is there any way that you can do this without Apple getting angry?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using iPodMusicPlayer would affect the actual iPod volume setting as well. If you want to avoid that, use this:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
// ...
MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
musicPlayer.volume = 1.0f;
```

As the user [holex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1214122/holex) correctly mentioned the property `volume` in `MPMusicPlayerController` is [deprecated in iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMusicPlayerController/volume).

Comment: Remember to add `MediaPlayer.framework` to your target's linking phase, and `#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>` in your source file.

Comment: it can be important to know the `volume` property is **deprecated** in iOS7. (further info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMusicPlayerController/volume)

Answer (score 23):

You can use a little trick:

```
  MPMusicPlayerController* musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
  musicPlayer.volume = 1; // device volume will be changed to maximum value
```

Comment: Use systemMusicPlayer instead of iPodMusicPlayer for IOS8+

Comment: The `volume` property is deprecated starting with iOS 7.0. You can check that [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMusicPlayerController/volume).

Answer (score 15):

You cannot change device volume programatically, however **[MPVolumeView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** (volume slider) is there to change device volume but only through user interaction.

MPVolumeView is a control in toolbox, you need to add **MediaPlayer.framework** in your project then MPVolumeView will be displayed in toolbox in interface builder.

**Edit 1:** MPVolumeView uses the device volume which is also used for ringing volume. [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) is there if you want application level volume. In this case you can use **volume** property to set your application volume (not device volume) programatically. However, you can use [UISlider](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html) control to get volume input from user and set to your AVAudioPlayer

Comment: Also note that it's only available in iOS 4.2, so you'll have to include version/class availability checking before you use it.

Comment: Nopes, a new property added in it to visible/hide it, the new property is only available in iOS 4.2, however I have uses it in iOS3.2, here I used it (iOS 3.2 or later), http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/msiradio/id399408266?mt=8

Comment: Hmm, that's a sort of setback. Would I be able to play a sound at a different volume than the ringer or system volume? I've seen quite a few apps do it already.

Comment: I currently use the AVAudioPlayer volume property, tied to a slider value. Works perfectly.

Comment: @seeafish, I am not sure until you do +1 :)