# UIView overlay when switching volume are there different api's?

Tags: ios, system, volume

I know there is the MPMusicPlayerController class in which I can set and change the volume of a media file - what is the class called that allows me to change the system volume? ringtones and alert sounds etc.

Nothing in the apple forums is a good help right now:-)

Cheers Jeff

Comment: I'd be very surprised if Apple allows third party developers to fiddle with this at all (feel free to correct me if I'm wrong though). Imagine the havoc you could wreak if you wanted to be malicious, or if you mistakenly muted/unmuted a device without the user's knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

...is your friend. See also this question - [iOS: Change Device Volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859402/ios-change-device-volume)

I believe Brian is correct in his comment that there's no way to programatically do it in the public API - the user *must* trigger the action, to stop apps from doing all sorts of naughty things.

Comment: Well the trigger is the point - like I want a button to set a volume, but the user has to press the button before it changes anything.

Comment: just checked your links to double check, but have come across those already:-) thanks though:-)

Comment: Yeah, there's no other way to programatically do it on iOS. Do file a feature request with Apple if it's something you'd like to see.

Comment: cool will do - just i'll bet as soon as it is released my app idea will go out the window, because someone will do it better a whole quicker then I will:-) Mind you then again it is probably already thought off, but for the reasons stated not implemented:-)