# Set playback volume with AVAudioPlayer with System Volume Change Indicator

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller

In iOS, I'm using `AVAudioPlayer` to change volume:

```
[avAudioPlayer setVolume:1.0];
```

where `avAudioPlayer` is an initialized `AVAudioPlayer instance. The System Volume Change Indicator does not show up.

But when I use the music player of `MPMusicPlayerController` to set volume, the System Volume Change Indicator shows up:

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:1.0];
```

How to make `AVAudioPlayer` shows the System Volume Change Indicator?

FYI, the Indicator I'm talking about this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything in this post? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7255006/4475605

Comment: Yes, first,  `float vol = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] outputVolume];` is read-only. Then, other solutions are about using `MPMusicPlayerController`, which I try to avoid (as I want to make the audio play within the App, not system-wide)

Comment: I guess I found my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4859632/188331). In short, it's not possible to do with `AVAudioPlayer`